# Display date based on required output format in android kotlin not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I am converting the UTC date to the Local timezone date in Android Kotlin. Converting UTC to the local time zone is working fine. I need the output format date in the specific required format as below:

June 12, 2020

For that, I have given the required output format but after conversion, it's not displaying in the specific format which I required. Below is my code:

Actually, as per my requirement, we have some default input date formats...I am passing the input date from the value that is coming from API
the input may come in any format from the API
so I am maintaining an enum class with all the input formats
for that, I have added the below condition

```
     val inputDate = "2020-09-23 7:38:00"
    
    for (item in DateFormats.values()) {
    try {
    val date = SimpleDateFormat(item.pattern).parse(inputDate)
    localDate = utcToLocalTimeZone(item.pattern,outputDateFormat,date.toString())
    break
    }
    catch(e:ParseException)
    {
    e.printStackTrace()
    }
    }
    so when I pass inputDate directly it is displaying the correct output format
    but when I convert date.tostring and passing that as input it's not converting to the required output format
        
    fun utcToLocalTimeZone(inputFormat : String,outputFormat : String,dateToConvert : String): String {
            var dateToReturn = dateToConvert
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat)
            sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            var gmt: Date? = null
            val sdfOutputToSend =
                SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat)
            sdfOutputToSend.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
          

  try {
            gmt = sdf.parse(dateToConvert)
            dateToReturn = sdfOutputToSend.format(gmt)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return dateToReturn
    }
```

Could you please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: Which date you are passing to the function? I have tried with "2018-09-10 22:01:00" at place of date.toString , It is working fine.

Comment: I am passing the date as val date = "2020-09-23 7:38:00", its converting to local timezone but format is showing as Wed Sep 23 07:38:00 GMT+10:00 2020 but i want the format in Sep 23,2020

Comment: It is also working fine. There is something wrong in passing date value. Can you share the whole snippet of code? I just want to check how you are getting date and passing it to the function.

Comment: hi i have updated my code. Can you check now

Comment: It is because your date string format is not correct for formatting when you are passing by converting in date patterns. You need to check date string value before passing it to the function. You can log values and debug for what is actually wrong with the date.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply follow this function.

```
fun getTime(
    originalString: String?,
    givenFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
    format: String
): String {
    var str = ""
    try {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(givenFormat, Locale.getDefault())
        val date = simpleDateFormat.parse(originalString ?: "")
        str = SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault()).format(
            date.ifNotNullOrElse({ it },
                { "" })
        )
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        return ""
    }
    return str
}
```

*`ifNotNullOrElse`*
To get desired value for given VALUE whether it is null or not

> Usage :
> any_kind_of_value.ifNotNullOrElse({your_return_value_if_given_value_is_not_null }, {
> your_return_value_if_given_value_is_null })

Now you call function like:

```
getTime(date.toString, givenFormat, format)
```

For EX:

givenFormat : `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

format : `"MMM dd, yyyy"`

date : `2020-09-26 11:23:40`

OutPut : `Sep 26, 2020`